# Sort two arrays from object depending on one of those arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [
   {a: 1, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [42, 7, 18, 5]},
   {a: 2, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [4, 101, 88, 3]},
   {a: 3, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [14, 10, 5, 12]},
   {a: 4, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [99, 2, 105, 101]}
];
```

I need to sort both `arr[x].b` and `arr[x].c` depending on `arr[x].c` values, if that makes sense. So, the final array should look like this:

```
arr = [
   {a: 1, b: ['mango', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple'], c: [5, 7, 18, 42]},
   {a: 2, b: ['mango', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana'], c: [3, 4, 88, 101]},
   {a: 3, b: ['orange', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple'], c: [5, 10, 12, 14]},
   {a: 4, b: ['banana', 'apple', 'mango', 'orange'], c: [2, 99, 101, 105]}
];
```

Comment: Note that chrome will not sort js array more than 20 rows.

Comment: @McBern, do you have a source of this statement?

Comment: @NinaScholz you can read it here: https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9312/sorting-in-javascript-handling-google-chromes-unstable-sort the sorter.js is here https://github.com/DMCChristopherOlsen/JavaScriptCustomSortingExample/blob/master/SortingExample/Scripts/Sorter.js `I mean chrome will not sort properly with js arrays > 10 rows`

Comment: @McBern, thanks for the link. actually, chrome's [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is stable.

Comment: Have you tried to sort using google chrome? with more than 10 rows in js array? I tried before, mozilla and IE but google chrome is not sorting properly. I didnt tried in safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each object, construct a `Map` whose keys are fruit strings and values are the associated *original* number in the `c` array. Sort the `c` array, then sort the `b` array based on the difference between the items in the map:

```js
const arr = [
   {a: 1, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [42, 7, 18, 5]},
   {a: 2, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [4, 101, 88, 3]},
   {a: 3, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [14, 10, 5, 12]},
   {a: 4, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [99, 2, 105, 101]}
];
Object.values(arr).forEach(({ b, c }) => {
  const fruitValues = c.reduce(
    (map, num, i) => map.set(b[i], num),
    new Map()
  );
  c.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  b.sort((a, b) => fruitValues.get(a) - fruitValues.get(b));
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can zip elements of `b` and `c` together, sort them by the `c` element, then unpack them back. With this method, only one `sort` is necessary, even if you are sorting multiple lists.

```js
const arr = [
   {a: 1, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [42, 7, 18, 5]},
   {a: 2, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [4, 101, 88, 3]},
   {a: 3, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [14, 10, 5, 12]},
   {a: 4, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [99, 2, 105, 101]}
];
Object.values(arr).forEach(row => {
  let sorting = row.b.map((e, i, a) => [e, row.c[i]]);
  sorting.sort(([b1, c1], [b2, c2]) => c1 - c2);
  row.b = sorting.map(([e, ]) => e);
  row.c = sorting.map(([, e]) => e);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the indices of the master array for sorting, sort them by the values of it and map all wanted array with a new order.

```js
var array = [{ a: 1, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [42, 7, 18, 5] }, { a: 2, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [4, 101, 88, 3] }, { a: 3, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [14, 10, 5, 12] }, { a: 4, b: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango'], c: [99, 2, 105, 101] }];

array.forEach(o => {
    var indices = [...o.c.keys()].sort((a, b) => o.c[a] - o.c[b]);
    ['b', 'c'].forEach(k => o[k] = indices.map(i => o[k][i]));
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```